# Coloring only certain bars in matplotlib barplot with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df=pd.DataFrame([770,215,179,107,83,82,70,60,57,54,52],index = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K']) 

ax = df.plot(kind='bar',stacked = False,alpha=0.75, rot=45,fontsize=20)
ax.legend_.remove()
for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=0).astype(np.int64), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(2, 10), textcoords='offset points',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('y ',fontsize=25)
plt.title('x',fontsize=30)
plt.show()
plt.save()
plt.close()
```

gave me : [image]

Now, I would just like to color B and H with different colors lets say red and orange. I would be more than thankful for any kind suggestion to achieve that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ax.patches[df.index.get_indexer(['B'])[0]].set_facecolor('r')

ax.patches[df.index.get_indexer(['H'])[0]].set_facecolor('orange')
```

[image]